# What are the values of the mass $m$ such that $mx''+25x = 12 \cos(36\pi t)$ will exhibit resonance?

Tags: dynamical-systems

$mx''+25x = 12 cos(36πt)$

my take on this:

${\omega_0} = \sqrt{k \over m} = \sqrt{25 \over m}$

$x_h = c_1cos({\omega_0}t) + c_2sin({\omega_0}t)$

$x_h = c_1cos(\sqrt{25 \over m} t) + c_2sin(\sqrt{25 \over m}t)$

$x_p = {{12 \over {m({\omega_0^2 - \omega^2})}}cos(36\pi t)} = {{12 \over {25-1296m^2}}cos(36\pi t)}$

but I am stuck here. am I on the wrong road?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Differential equation with resonance](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2282975/differential-equation-with-resonance). Same question, different numbers and a $\sin$ instead of a $\cos$.

Comment: I assume you're finding the general solution since there are no initial conditions. Is that right?

Comment: @TobyMak thank you! mostly yes, because I didn't know in which direction to go. :)

Comment: Remember that you can always modify the particular solution with terms from the complimentary one. So you could also use a modified $$x_p=A\frac{\cos(ω_0t)-\cos(ωt)}{ω_0^2-ω^2}$$ with a now obvious difference quotient for $ω_0-ω\to 0$.